# Why does this query work with a CTE, but not with a derived table?

Tags: sql-server, errors

I was looking to identify the 'Email' that was duplicated.

The two simplest ways I thought of are shown below, however for some reason **the query using the derived table produces the error: Incorrect syntax near ')'.**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Email VARCHAR(255)
    )

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES 
    (1, 'a@b.com'),
    (2, 'c@d.com'),
    (3, 'a@b.com')

-- Fails to run
SELECT Email
FROM (
    SELECT Email, COUNT(*) AS Count_
    FROM #TEMP
    GROUP BY Email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

-- Runs successfully
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Email, COUNT(*) Count_
    FROM #TEMP
    GROUP BY Email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
SELECT Email FROM cte
```

I am wanting to understand why this may be. What is the issue with the query using the derived table?

Comment: Additionally, don't put the `;` in front of the statement. Make sure you **end** every statement with it:  https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: Please include the error message when asking a question. It does provide valuable information for the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an alias for the derived table.

[Books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - Emphasis mine

> When a derived table, rowset or table-valued function, or operator clause (such as PIVOT or UNPIVOT) is used, the **required table_alias at the end of the clause** is the associated table name for all columns, including grouping columns, returned.